# How to commit only tracked files in VS Code?

Tags: git, visual-studio-code

"git status" shows following three info:

1. Changes to be committed (staged changes)
2. Changes not staged for commit (not staged changes)
3. Untracked files

I used to `git commit -a`, which commits 1 and 2.
However VS Code `Commit All` commits 1, 2, and 3; `Commit Staged` commits 1.

Comment: Hi axiac, your suggested operation is error prone. People could drag untracked files by mistake.

Comment: People can do anything by mistake but this is not the problem with my suggestion. The problem is that it is not possible to drag the items from one section to another. I wrote my previous comment without having an instance of VSCode at hand; I have one now and I discovered the sad truth. :-(

Comment: You can still use `git commit -a` in the terminal integrated in VSCode.

Answer (score 0):

'git commit -a' means commit all files which tracked and modified.
Try 
'git add selected/file/path'
then 'git commit -m "commit message"'

Answer (score -2):

Update files currently being tracked

`git add -u`

Commit updated files

`git commit -m <commit message>`