# Differences between Commit, Commit Staged, and Commit All in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, commit, git-commit

There are three commands for Git committing in Visual Studio Code:

- Commit
- Commit Staged
- Commit All

[image]

What are the differences between them?

- I expect *Commit Staged* works as a regular [`git commit`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-commit) command.
- I’ve found that [*Commit All* commits unstaged and untracked files](https://stackoverflow.com/q/49549490/711006), too. (Similarly to [*Commit All* in the “classic” Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/git/commits?view=azure-devops&tabs=visual-studio).)
- **However, what does *Commit* do, and how does it differ from the two commands above?**

Unfortunately, I have not found any documentation or web pages on this. (I am not interested in the differences between `git pull` and `git fetch` or *commit – amend* or *commit – signed off* as most searches suggest – all of these are documented well. The *Commit* command is also missing in the comprehensive list in the German article [Visual Studio Code (7): Git als Quellcodeverwaltung einsetzen](https://www.microsoft.com/de-de/techwiese/know-how/visual-studio-code-07-git-als-quellcodeverwaltung-einsetzen.aspx), for example.)

Comment: I would guess it's the same thing provided by different plugins. Uninstall plugins and see what happens and then reinstall them one by one.

Comment: @fredrik This happens with no extension installed (you meant extensions, didn’t you?).

Answer (score 2):

I tried to run "Commit" from my instance of VS Code, and it prompted me with a message :

> There are no staged changes to commit.
> Would you like to stage all your changes and commit them directly ?
>
> [Never] [Cancel] [Always] [Yes]

So my guess is : it's just a command which checks your local configuration or interactively asks you what to do.
In the end, it applies either "Commit staged" or "Commit all".

Comment: The same happens if you issue *Commit Staged* or *Commit All* with nothing staged (and the option *Git: Suggest Smart Commit* enabled)…

Comment: hmmm, noted. I'm not a great expert on VSCode's GUI for git anyway.

Answer (score 1):

I observed the VS Code behaviour by the **git log window** and I discovered that both `commit` and `commit all` option, it logs a `git add -A -- .` so the result is the same.

```
> git add -A -- .
> git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file -
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
> git ls-tree -l HEAD -- /home/antonio/tmp/vscode/f9
> git show --textconv HEAD:f9
> git status -z -u
> git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
> git for-each-ref --format=%(refname)%00%(upstream:short)%00%(objectname)%00%(upstream:track) refs/heads/master refs/remotes/master
> git for-each-ref --sort -committerdate --format %(refname) %(objectname) %(*objectname)
> git remote --verbose
> git config --get commit.template
```

In my opinion it maybe a bug!